# "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" in Matlab when assigning to a struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, struct, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to assign values to an array contained within a struct in Matlab. I am perplexed by the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error, because as far as I can tell, I am following the example of the official documentation and doing something that has worked for me in the past. I hope this is enough relevant context:

```
for m = 1:tally
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).scans = files{m};
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(1).name = 'button_press';
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(1).onset = events.bp.onsets{m};
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(1).duration = 0;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(1).tmod = 0;
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(1).pmod = struct('name', {}, 'param', {}, 'poly', {});

    sess_onsets = events.conditions.sessions(tally).onsets{1};
    for n = 1:numel(sess_onsets)
        len = numel(sess_onsets{n});
        cond_list = events.conditions.names{tally};
        cond_onsets = sess_onsets{n};
        matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1).name = cond_list{n};
        matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1).onset = cond_onsets;
        matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1).duration = repmat([4], len, 1);
        matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1).tmod = 0;
        matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1).pmod = struct('name', {}, 'param', {}, 'poly', {});
    end

    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).multi = {''};
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).regress = struct('name', {}, 'val', {});
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).multi_reg = rp{k};
    matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).hpf = 128;
end
```

The error comes on this line:

```
matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1).name = cond_list{n};
```

When I step to this line in the debugger, it is this expression

```
matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1)
```

that gives the "index exceeds matrix dimensions error." It does this even when n is 1. Abstractly, based on my experience with other languages, that makes sense.  Cond is length 1 and I'm trying to assign to the second slot.  But it doesn't make sense to me based on my experience with and (obviously flawed) knowledge of arrays in Matlab structs.  In the past I've just made a struct array longer by announcing I'm going to with the new subscript.

Here are [Matlab's instructions for how to assign to a struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html).  The only difference I can see is that they don't use the (1) subscript the first time they assign to the array, and I tried that and it made no difference.

This code works fine:

```
>> a.b(1).name = 'apple';
>> a.b(2).name = 'banana'
a = b: [1x2 struct]
```

I am struggling to understand the difference.  Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I need to give more information.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure an array of structs can hold an array of any type as a field. So while `a.b(1).name` works, AFAIK `a.b(1).c(1).name` will not.

Comment: @sobek, thanks for your help, but unless I misunderstand you, that can't be right.  

`>> a.b.sess(1).cond(1).name = 'apple';
>> a.b.sess(1).cond(2).name = 'banana';
>> a.b.sess(2).cond(1).name = 'apple';
>> a.b.sess(2).cond(2).name = 'banana'
a = b: [1x1 struct]`

runs without error.  I patterned my program from code automatically generated by the software program SPM.  The automatically generated code (too long to paste here) runs without error.

Comment: Have you looked at the loop variables at the time the error occurs? Does it happen at the first execution of either loop?

Comment: @sobek, I have, and yes, it happens at first execution of both loops.

Comment: It is indeed weird, i must admit i fail to see an error. Have you tried growing the struct array by concatenation, like `arrayStruct = [arrayStruct , newFields]`?

Comment: @sobek, I'm not sure if this is what you meant (apologies -- I'm not a very experienced programmer), but I tried adding this: `matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond = [matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1)] `  before the line where I try to assign to `cond(n+1).name`.  No cigar.  Fails with the same error, and the `matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1)` still throws that exception in the debugger.

Comment: Tough problem: It sounds like you already verified that `cond_list` is populated, but if you haven't you could try commenting out the line that is erroring. I would expect it to error on the next line, if not, look at the size of `cond_list`. Looking at your code the line `cond_list = events.conditions.names{tally};` doesn't seem right to me, specifically the `{tally}`, but you would know better

Comment: You misunderstood me a little. The concatenation is used to get rid of the index based growing. `newFields` in my example above needs to be a struct with the exact same fields as `matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(1)`, once `newFields` is created, you add it to the end of your existing struct. `matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond = [matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond, newFields]` with `newFields = struct('name',value,'onset',value,'duration',value,'tmod',value,'pmod',value)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to all who tried to help me.  I am feeling like a doof, and somewhat guilty for not communicating accurate information to people who were trying to help me. This question should have been titled "I don't know how to use a debugger."  I thought it was failing on the first execution because when I stepped to that line and pasted in

```
matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1)
```

I got an error.  But I now understand that the reason for that error is that pasting in that expression does not do the work of creating the next array element -- I needed

```
matlabbatch{2}.spm.stats.fmri_spec.sess(m).cond(n+1).name = foo
```

to make that element exist.  If I had clicked "continue" I would have realized that the real failure was in cond_list{n} when n = 5.  This was just a conceptual failure in my code, and not anything anyone else would likely have recognized.  Thanks very much for your time, and I'm sorry for leading you astray with my claims.